# Extract K-means cluster information Apache Spark into JSON

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I will be implementing [k-means](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-clustering.html#examples) on Spark. But I need cluster info stored in JSON. how can it be done?

Note: Python or Scala will also do.

Thank in advance!

Comment: You copied the code that's on the example page. What are we supposed to do with it ?

Comment: Look at the model export api:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/mllib-pmml-model-export.html

Comment: @eliasah sorry i'm new to spark and all. i would be implementing k-mean same as that sample code, and that cluster which we are getting at end, i need that information in JSON and store it in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KMeansModel.clusterCenters` is just a local data structure (`Array[Vector]` in Scala / Java, a list of NumPy array in Python). It means you can use standard JSON processing libraries. For example with Python:

```py
import json
json.dumps({"centers": [list(x) for x in clusters.clusterCenters]})
```

If JSONL is acceptable you can also parallelize centers and use `DataFrameWriter.write.json`.

```scala
val clusters: org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel = ???
sc.parallelize(clusters.clusterCenters.zipWithIndex, 1)
  .toDF("center", "id")
  .write.json("centers.jsonl")
```